# How are units calculated in Analyze duplicates?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

What is the meaning of `number of statements` and `number of expressions` in the formula used to calculate `units` in Analyze duplicates?

> - **Skip duplicates simpler than:**
>
> (...)
>
> The exact value of units can be calculated as follows:
>
> `units = 2 * number of statements + number of expressions`

This functionality is common to [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-duplicates.html#configure-inspection) and [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/analyzing-duplicates.html#configure-duplicates-analysis).

Comment: I would like answers to contain an example.

Comment: I also searched the JetBrains tracker but haven't found an explanation.